# Div and Image vertically missalligned when height: 100vh

Tags: html, css, display, object-fit

Can someone please tell me why the div and the image are vertically separated?

```
<div style="height: 100vh; display: inline-block;width: 50%; background-color: blue">TEST
</div><!--
--><img src="photos/openening.jpg" alt="SICK SHOT" style="height:100vh; display: inline-block; width: 50%; object-fit:cover;">
```

For me the website looks like that:
[Image](https://i.ibb.co/4fzs0Wf/help.png)
(I took a black Image for this.)

And if you are able to tell me the reason behind that, can you please also tell me a way to correct it, so both of those start at the same height. That it looks somehow like the following website:
[petermckinnon](https://petermckinnon.com)
 I would also be open for some different approaches to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the image's vertical alignment property puts it inline with the top of the div. I've corrected it in the example below:

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; display: inline-block;width: 50%; background-color: blue">TEST
</div><!--
--><img src="photos/openening.jpg" alt="SICK SHOT" style="height:100vh; display: inline-block; width: 50%; vertical-align:bottom; background: black; object-fit:cover;">
```

Comment: Hell yes, thank you!!!

Comment: Schweini, if this answers your question, you should mark it as "Accepted" and give it an up-vote so others know it was beneficial.